# Can all functional powers of a diffeomorphism have bounded derivatives?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f$ be an increasing diffeomorphism of $\mathbb R$ and let $f^n$, for $n>0$, denote $f$ composed with itself $n$ times. Similarly, let $f^{-n}$, for $n>0$, denote $f^{-1}$ composed with itself $n$ times. Suppose that the derivative of $f^n$ is uniformly bounded by the same constant $C$for all $n\in {\mathbb Z}$, i.e. 
$(f^n)'(x)<C$ for all $n\in {\mathbb Z}$ and for all $x\in {\mathbb R}$. Does that imply that $f$ is the identity?

Comment: What about the identity's evil twin?

Comment: @hardmath isn't the evil twin decreasing?

Comment: For a less trivial diffeo, let $f$ be the identity except over some open bounded interval. Such an $f$ can be a diffeomorphism with use of bump functions.

Comment: Indeed it is.  I forgot that $f$ should increase by the end of the question.

Comment: @PVAL I had the same thought, but it isn't completely clear to me how to ensure the uniform (in $n$) bound on the derivatives.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It can be $f(x)=x+1$. Okay, this is somewhat trivial. But this example can be conjugated by any diffeomorphism $\phi:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ to produce 
$$f(x) = \phi^{-1}(\phi(x)+1)$$
which is nonlinear in general. Note that 
$$f^n(x) = \phi^{-1}(\phi(x)+n)$$
If $\phi$ is such that $c\le \phi'\le C$ for some positive constants $c,C$, then $$|(f^n)'|\le C/c$$ for all $n$.